# Use content of class member as variable name

Tags: php, dynamic

I tried to use the content of a class member to access a method variable:

```
protected function method() {
    $var1 = 'no';
    $var2 = 'no';

    if ($this->data['x']['y'] != 'bums') {
        $$this->data['x']['y'] = 'yes';

        ${$this->data['x']['y']} = 'yes';
    }
}
```

`$this->data['x']['y']` can have the contents *var1* or *var2* in this case.
But why can't I use that way to access the method variables?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/Ccstl or http://ideone.com/THz2H I _can_ access variables this way (even if I think, that variable variables are ugly )

Comment: Please try it with/inner class methods. In my example there are no security checks, but I have all neccessary checks.

Comment: There are many things that you can do that you shouldn't. I would recommend finding another way to meet your requirement.

Comment: I don't know, why do you come to the conclusion, that methods may change anything, but ok: http://ideone.com/i3v3i Still works fine. I probably would help you, but even if I try, I cant find any problem...

Comment: Not it works. I don't know why, thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable variables can be a security risk.  Even if you check them, there's no point in opening up another vector where you can make a mistake.  Use arrays instead, they're easier to understand and cleaner anyway.

```
protected function method() {
    $var = array(
        1 => 'no',
        2 => 'no',
    );

    if ($this->data['x']['y'] != 'bums') {
        $var[$this->data['x']['y']] = 'yes';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always a bad and unsecure practise to use $$whatever:

It would be much better to change to code to:

```
protected function method() {
    $var1 = 'no';
    $var2 = 'no';

    switch ($this->data['x']['y']) {
       case 'var1':
           $var1 = 'yes';
           break;
       case 'var2':
           $var2 = 'yes';
           break;
    }
}
```

HTH, Andreas

Comment: Why shall it be unsecure, when there are all neccessary checks? Because it is an example I haven't posted the checks.

Comment: You did not mention checks and I did see it in your code. My version includes already a check. If you want to do it absolutely dynamic why do you try it this way: 
    $value = $this->data['x']['y']; 
    $$value = 'yes'; 
That should work.

Comment: @Andreas: Is the same as the example in the question, that works (see links in the comments).

Comment: Alright, I thought it is the normal way to check every thing. Thanks for your advice, but my code works now.

Comment: @KingCrunch: I know and I would not use this kind of programming. But storing in a local variable works.

Comment: @Andreas: It wasn't my intention to tell you, what you should do and what not (but yes, I don't like variable variables very much ;)). Its just `${$this->data['x']['y']} = 'yes';` works and its the same as `$value = $this->data['x']['y']; $$value = 'yes';`. There is no need for a local variable.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Okay, thanks. I never tried this with a class property.